# How to remove column name

Tags: r

I have an easy question I can seem to figure out. I am trying to remove a column name. I am trying to make some tables with formattable and I don't like the column name that is there. Here is what the table looks like now.

```
df <- data.frame(
  "test" = c("Average age of Diagnosis", "Average Life Space", "Average Number of Dogs Diagnosised with MR"), 
  "2008-2018" = c(28, 27, 30),
  "Sample size" = c(12,23,34),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE, check.names=FALSE)
```

I want to remove column1 so I tried this

```
df <- data.frame(
  "" = c("Average age of Diagnosis", "Average Life Space", "Average Number of Dogs Diagnosised with MR"), 
  "2008-2018" = c(28, 27, 30),
  "Sample size" = c(12,23,34),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE, check.names=FALSE)
```

> Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name

which is clearly related to me removing the column name. Is there a way to fix this? I just wanted to remove the name for `test`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `" "` instead of `""`. Is this sufficient for you?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the column name? Maybe you need to set your `test` variable as rowname?

Comment: @kath BINGO!!! that solved my problem. I knew it was something simple like that. Thanks so much!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue I used Kath suggestion (see comment to the original question). To fix this problem I used the following

```
df <- data.frame(
  " " = c("Average age of Diagnosis", "Average Life Space", "Average Number of Dogs Diagnosised with MR"), 
  "2008-2018" = c(28, 27, 30),
  "Sample size" = c(12,23,34),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE, check.names=FALSE)
```

It is subtly different from my original post but there is a space between the `""`.

I am using this ability to make some figures and I didn't want anything in that column name

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
colnames(df)[1] <- ''
```

Comment: replace 1 by the column location you want

Comment: I have tried this but I get this back `Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "") : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can lean from it - why should one try that?